# "Reset" a divs state with jquery waypoints

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, jquery-waypoints

I have script which animates the opacity of a div when the user scrolls to a certain point, thanks to the jquery waypoints plugin. The problem is the animation only fires once, and I'd like to have it so if the user scrolls back up and scrolls down again it happens again.

This is my script, which also uses modernizr.js.

```
if ( $("html").hasClass("no-touch") ) {
    $('#main-content').waypoint(function() {
        $('#lvdi').animate({opacity:1}, 600);
    }, { offset: '25%' });
};
```

HTML

```
<section id="home">
    <div id="home-inner-wrap" class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="row">            
                <div class="col-66 center-66">
                ~ Content ~
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section id="main-content">
 ~ Content ~
</section>
```

Comment: Could you provide your HTML?

Comment: HTML has been added, cheers

Comment: Try something like this is that what you want to achieve? http://jsfiddle.net/y7SsU/2/

Comment: Eduardo Quintana, can you make that an answer and not a comment? It is correct, use the `direction` parameter and if it is "up" fadeOut, otherwise fadeIn.

Comment: Yeah, thanks Eduardo Quintana that works great!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reset the styles once #main-content div is out of view. To do this, add a class when waypoint is triggered:

```
if ( $("html").hasClass("no-touch") ) {
    $('#main-content').waypoint(function() {
        $('#lvdi').animate({opacity:1}, 600);
        $('#lvdi').addClass("animated");

    }, { offset: '25%' });
};
```

And then use [ScrollSpy](https://github.com/thesmart/jquery-scrollspy) plugin to listen to the exit event, reset the styles and remove the class you have added when it is out of view.

```
$('#main-content').on('scrollSpy:exit',function(){
    if($(this).hasClass('animated')) {
       $('#lvdi').css({'opacity' : 0}).removeClass('animated');
    }

});
```